# Доступ к AppData у пользователя с русским именем

Tags: windows, qt5, locale

Не могу получить доступ к русскому пользователю и его `AppData\Local`, где лежат конфиги, генерируемые в *Python*. `qgetenv("USERNAME")` возвращает либо вопросительные знаки, либо нечитаемые символы. Варианты с `.toUtf8`, `.toLocal8Bit`, `.toLatin1`, `QTextCodec`, `toStdString`, `toStdWString` были испробованы. Может я делаю что-то не так? Прошу помощи.

Используемая версия *Qt5.6*, компилятор *VS2015*, сборка *CMake*.

Answer (score 0):

Для получения путей до стандартных директорий существует специальный класс [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html). Конкретно по Вашей проблеме решение будет выглядеть так:

```
QStandardPaths::displayName(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation);
```

Нужно посмотреть, что конкретно оно вернёт, т.к. судя по документации, там может быть несколько путей — в этом случае нужно будет выбрать один.